# Как сортировать сначала по одному столбцу, а после по другому?

Tags: mysql, sql

Вот у меня есть код:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p JOIN grouplists g ON p.groupid=g.groupid WHERE g.usid = '1' AND p.reposts>=g.reposts AND p.likes>=g.likes ORDER BY `p`.`date` DESC, `g`.`rating` DESC LIMIT 40
```

Этот код, по идее, должен сначала сортировать по убыванию столбца `date` в таблице `posts`, а потом, из уже отсортированных постов, по убыванию столбца `rating` из таблицы `grouplists`. Но по `rating` этот запрос не сортирует, а сортирует по `date`. В чем может быть проблема? Как это исправить?

В `date` находятся разные метки времени (unix timestamp), в `rating` числа от 1 до 10.

[image: данные в столбцах]

Comment: очень поможет, если вы структуру таблиц и примерные данные предоставите

Comment: @cyadvert я добавил в вопрос немного про содержимое полей.

Comment: Покажите несколько строк в том порядке, в котором получается результат и укажите в каких строках вы видите проблему (интересуют только столбцы `rating` и `date`)

Comment: @tutankhamun снова обновил вопрос

Comment: У вас нет повторяющихся дат потому что даты в unixtime. Поэтому и `rating` сортировка не проходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сортировка по `rating` происходит только среди строк с равными значениями полей `date`

**Обновлено**

Если вы хотите получить последние 40 строк по дате и потом отсортировать полученные строки по рейтингу воспользуйтесь вложенным запросом

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.*, g.`rating` 
        FROM `posts` p
        JOIN `grouplists` g 
            ON p.`groupid` = g.`groupid` 
        WHERE g.`usid` = '1' 
            AND p.`reposts` >= g.`reposts` 
            AND p.`likes` >= g.`likes` 
        ORDER BY p.`date` DESC
        LIMIT 40
) AS tmp ORDER BY tmp.`rating` DESC
```

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы сортировка по `rating` происходила среди строк с разными значениями `date`?

Comment: я пробовал. Мне нужно чтобы эти 40 строк, которые я получаю, сначала сортировались именно по дате, а потом уже по рейтингу.

Comment: @DeFF По сути вы хотите получить последние 40 строк по дате и потом отсортировать полученные строки по рейтингу?

Comment: Именно так мне и нужно.

Comment: #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: @DeFF Перечислите явно столбцы во вложенном запросе или сделайте так, как в еще раз обновленном ответе

Comment: спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Переведите unixtime в дату и сортируйте потом.:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`p`.`date`)) as theDate, p.* FROM posts p 
JOIN grouplists g ON p.groupid=g.groupid 
WHERE g.usid = '1' AND p.reposts>=g.reposts AND p.likes>=g.likes 
ORDER BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`p`.`date`)) DESC, `g`.`rating` DESC LIMIT 40
```

Comment: Так оно тоже очень странно сортирует. Сначала выводит больше, потом меньшее, а потом снова большее (в `rating`)

Comment: я обновил ответ. Добавил колонку даты в результат. Посмотрите - сначал он сортирует по новой колонке даты, а уже потом по рейтингу

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но переводить даты кучу раз это не очень удобно в моём случае.